# How to import a file with delimiters irregular with the csv module in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, import, delimiter

I suppose that is a very simple question, but no for me until now...
I have a file with the columns like this:

```
1 2  3 4  5   3
6 7 -8 9  0   5
4 8 -4 6 -7   8
```

and I have this code in python:

```
import csv

MyValues = [] #create an empty list
values = csv.reader(open('myfile', 'rb'), delimiter=' ')
for row in values:
    MyValues.append(row[5] if len(row)>4 else None)
print MyValues
```

The problem is that the delimiter is not only a space, sometimes is two or 3 spaces. Until now I could not fix, even using sniffer or dialect routines... 
Someone have any idea how can I import the columns?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the csv module, just use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on each line:

```
MyValues = []
for line in open('myfile'):
    row = line.split()
    MyValues.append(row[5] if len(row)>4 else None)
print MyValues
```

`str.split()` splits the string on whitespace by default, and consecutive whitespace characters will be treated as a single delimiter.